# Can I bind a raw html node in Ember/handlebars?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using a library that creates html elements on the fly, and I want to bind those in my view, raw. Something like this:

In my view:

```
myNodeList: [],
onElementCreated: function(element) {
    myNodeList.pushObject(element);
}
```

and in my template:

```
{{#each node in myNodeList}}
   //how do I render the node raw?
   //{{{node}}} renders [object]
   //{{{node.outerHTML}}} 
   //     renders a clone of the node, but I want the actual node, not a clone
{{/each}}
```

Comment: BTW, push won't be recognize by Ember, you'll want to use `pushObject`

Comment: Oh I skimmed the question, the answer is no you can't through handlebars, you could possibly do it through the view layer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CollectionView:

```
myNodeList: Ember.CollectionView.create({
    content: [],
    itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
       template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{view.content}}')
    })
}),
onElementCreated: function(element) {
    myNodeList.get('content').pushObject(element);
}
```

template:

```
{{view myNodeList}}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, and it's effectively the same as my example of what doesn't work in my question. It tries to render the node with `{{node}}` which outputs `[object]` because the node is an object, not a string.